# Understanding Laravel View Composers: Where does my view composer belong?

Tags: php, laravel

I am reading through the Laravel documentation to get a deeper understanding and this would be the second time I run into a bit of confusion.

Not long ago, I was working through a Laracasts video in which we implement a View composer in our `AppServicesProvider` register method.

Which looks like this:

```
public function register()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.sidebar', function ($view) {
        $archives = \App\Post::archives();
        $tags = \App\Tag::has('posts')->pluck('name');
        $view->with(compact('archives', 'tags'));
    });
}
```

What this does, is it makes archives and tags available for our sidebar view, which is available in almost every page. (The Laracast videos involved building a blog from scratch)

So far so good.

Today, as I am reading through the documentation of a view composer, I encounter [this example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers):

```
/**
 * Register bindings in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    // Using class based composers...
    View::composer(
        'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
    );

    // Using Closure based composers...
    View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
        //
    });
}
```

Now, I THINK I understand creating your own `ComposerServiceProvider` and class based composers vs closure based. The source of my confusion is that this is being done in the `boot()` method vs the `register()` method.

It's totally possible that I wrote this in the wrong place. If I think about it, it almost doesn't make sense for it to be in the `register()` method, since register should only be used to register services. The boot is called after ALL the register methods are called. If someone could clear this up for me I would appreciate it!

> Does view composer belong in the `register()` method or `boot()` method? And
>   if it belongs in the `register()` method, is it just a coincidence that
>   it still works for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing the answer given by a user in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/difference-between-boot-and-register-method) question:

> ### Difference between boot and register method?
>
> I actually just learned the difference last night from Taylor's book.
>   Here is an excerpt about it:
>
> “After all providers have been registered, they are “booted”. This
>   will fire the boot method on each provider. A common mistake when
>   using service providers is attempting to use the services provided by
>   another provider in the register method. Since, within the register
>   method, we have no guarantee all other providers have been loaded, the
>   service you are trying to use may not be available yet. So, service
>   provider code that uses other services should always live in the boot
>   method. The register method should only be used for, you guessed it,
>   registering services with the container. Within the boot method, you
>   may do whatever you like: register event listeners, include a routes
>   file, register filters, or anything else you can imagine.”
>
> So the register one is just for binding. The boot one is to actually
>   trigger something to happen.

Answer (score 2):

They should be placed in the boot method. The register method does not guarantee dependencies will be resolved when you may need them. With the boot method you have that guarantee. And as you mentioned, ideally you should create a separate service provider for the view composers.